# Can I use the MIT license as Terms and Conditions on a personal project

Tags: internet, privacy, terms-of-service

I'm making a web app which:

- is a personal project,
- is open source,
- is completely free,
- doesn't have any kind of login system (users can't create accounts),
- doesn't collect personal user data,
- doesn't use cookies.

And I provide two things:

- the source code of the app (on GitHub),
- a hosted version of the app, readily usable for everyone who accesses the website.

In the principle, it's very similar to this app, for instance: https://squoosh.app

I like the MIT license, which basically says: « I'm giving this to the world, anyone can do anything with it, but I can't be held responsible for anything. »

So I license the source code of the app with the MIT license.

My questions:

- Do I need Terms and Conditions, and/or a privacy policy, on the website hosting the app?
- If yes, can I use the MIT license (replacing "software" by "application") on it? Something like this:

```
THIS APPLICATION IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE APPLICATION OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
APPLICATION.
```

Would that work to limit my liability?

(The Squoosh app doesn't have Ts&Cs, which makes me wondering if the authors could be liable for anything. This is another question that I asked [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101296/what-are-the-risks-if-any-of-not-having-terms-and-conditions-and-a-privacy-pol)).

Comment: You might not physically be able to get out of at least "processing" personal data if you operate a web server: the server needs the client IP in memory in order to reply to it. And generally the server also logs it, unless you have configured it otherwise. There might be somewhere where you are for some reason legally required to inform users of these basic facts of how the web works.

Answer (score 2):

These two things are independent. The MIT license is for the source code, it basically means that anyone can download and copy the source code, use it for his own projects and manipulate it to his needs.

The Terms of Use are for the website offering a certain service. There you describe what users are allowed to do on your website and what not. Linked to it is typically a data privacy disclaimer, telling users of the website that their IPs will be logged and that their E-Mails will be stored (if there's something like a login page on that website).

So you don't need any terms of use for the source code part, but you need it as soon as you provide a life server running the code. Somebody else could run his own server with an adapted version of the software and different terms, but many jurisdictions meanwhile require that some terms of use and often also some contact data can be found on the website. Any website that does not have this is usually a scam and extra caution is advised.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. All Ts&Cs templates I've found are long and have parts like "liability will not excess $XXX", "Disputes will be resolved in XXX".

Isn't it possible to do something much simpler?

If we replace "software" by "application" in the MIT license, then it sounds very much like Ts&Cs. Why couldn't I use this?

Seeing my question downvoted makes me think that I didn't ask it well. So I posted another one that is more specific: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/101296/what-exactly-are-the-risks-of-not-having-terms-and-conditions-and-a-privacy-po

Comment: Yea, I think to answer _that_ question, it should be asked more specifically.

Comment: I edited this question to make it more specific: I included an example of tweaked MIT license, let me know if you have any information about the possibility to use this as Ts&Cs to limit my liability :-)

Comment: @Zwyx You're still not getting it. The MIT license has nothing to do with users of your service. It only applies to people copying and redistributing the software. The situation where a license may include T&C is when you're distributing software for end users to use on their own; this is usually called an EULA (End User License Agreement). An example would be software like Excel.